# Can't stop validation on non-visible fields?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 5 form that I'm using jQuery validation on. My issue is that based on a specific condition I have some textboxes that are not being written out in the form. However, the DataAnnotation is set to Required so that it will validate if they are visible.

Thing is that my form is not posting because of the Required DataAnnotation on the fields that are not visible.

I did some looking around and found a suggestion to give my form an ID and Name then just the following jQuery. I did view the source on the page and the form name is correct but it's still trying to validate the field that are not visible.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#requestForm").validate({ ignore: ":not(:visible)" });
    });        
</script>
```

Just to clarify, these are not hidden fields. They are textboxes that are not written out in the view. Here is the code in the View. In my scenario this is not a partial so these textboxes are just not written out to the page, yet it's causing the Model to not be valid which stops it from being posted.

```
if (Model.RequestType.ToLower() == "partial")
{

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label class="control-label">From</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PartialFrom, new { @maxlength = "4", @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PartialFrom, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: you can also use it like  $("#myform").validate({
   ignore: ":hidden"
});

Comment: This makes no sense. If your not generating the inputs, then client side validation cannot be performed on something that does not exist. Its simply impossible (and hidden inputs are not validated by default so even if they were hidden, it would not stop the form submitting). If you form is not submitting, then its something else that's the issue. But if you really mean that it is hitting the POST method and `ModelState` is invalid, then that is a different issue.

Comment: It was hitting the POST and then the Model state was looking at it as being required even though the input box was not visible. I ended up getting around the issue by using https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code before the vaidation plugin code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        ignore: []
    });
});
```

You can check [JQUERY VALIDATION LOGS](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/blob/master/changelog.md#190)

Comment: When you say to add it before he validation plugin, I'm using the built in bundling from MVC so I have a @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") in my _Layout.cshtml page. My jQuery code I was testing is directly on my view (Index.cshtml). How would I make it so that it's before the plugin code?